# Finding recursive formula for repeated term on sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence

$$3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,...$$

The pattern is so difficult. The best i can do is knowing that after jumping to the "next number" it has length $2+2n$. I mean i have $3$ as initial value. And first repeated term has lenght $2+2(1)=4$.  ($4$ repeated term) The second number is $4$ and its length is $2+2(2)=6$. ($6$ repeated term). The third number is $5$ and its length is $2+2(3)=8$. ($8$ repeated term)

How to find the recursive formula? I'm really stuck. Please help me.

Comment: So four $3$s, six $4$, eight $5$s and presumably ten $6$ etc.  Something like a rounded square root might give a closed form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_0=3;\;a_n=a_{n-1}+\left\lfloor -\text{frac}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{4 n+9}-3\right)\right)\right\rfloor +1$$
where $\text{frac}(x)$ is the fractional part of $x$.

From $0$ to $20$ we have
$$\{3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6\}$$

This works because $\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{4 n+9}-3\right)$ is integer when $n=k^2+3k$ which give exactly the sequence $4,10,18,\ldots$ when the number of the given sequence must increase by one.

I mean $3,3,3,3,\mathbf{4},4,4,4,4,4,\mathbf{5},5,5,5,\ldots$

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the answer. so I've tested it using Wolfram Alpha until $n = 18$, but it looks like the sequence's shifting to the left. I mean shouldn't the initial value be $a_0 = 3$ instead of $a_1 = 3$?. Bcz `3+floor(-frac(1/2(√(4(4)+9)-3)))+1=4` $(a_4=4)$ since the number $3$ should have $4$ repeated term?

Comment: @user516076 Edited to correct the answer, thank you